# How to count values conditionally in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, count, group-by

I have an index table of entity attribute values that looks like this:

`+-----------+--------------+----------+-------+
| entity_id | attribute_id | store_id | value |
+-----------+--------------+----------+-------+
|        38 |          190 |        1 |    22 |
|        38 |          190 |        1 |    23 |
|        39 |          190 |        1 |    22 |
|        39 |          190 |        1 |    23 |
|        39 |          190 |        1 |    42 |
|        40 |          190 |        1 |    22 |
|        41 |          190 |        1 |    54 |
|        42 |          190 |        1 |    54 |
|        43 |          190 |        1 |    22 |
|        44 |          190 |        1 |    22 |
|        45 |          190 |        1 |    54 |
+-----------+--------------+----------+-------+`

As you can see, a single entity can have multiple values for a single attribute (`entity_id` 38 has `value`s 22,23) and these values are not unique per entity (`entity_id` 38,39 both share `value` 22).

The first problem to solve is getting the number of distinct entities per value; this is easily accomplished with:

```
SELECT value, COUNT(entity_id) AS count
FROM catalog_product_index_eav
WHERE attribute_id=190
GROUP BY value;
```

which results in:

`+-------+-------+
| value | count |
+-------+-------+
|    22 |     5 |
|    23 |     2 |
|    42 |     1 |
|    54 |     3 |
+-------+-------+`

My question is how can I nest an OR condition in this count, namely: for some **specific** value Y, for each value X, count the number of entities that have either value X or Y.

I would like to do this in a single query. For instance, for `attribute_id` 190 and `value` 23, the output from above example should be:

`+-------+-------+
| value | count |
+-------+-------+
|    22 |     5 | # all entities with value 22 happen to have 23 as well 
|    23 |     2 |   that is, one is a subset of the other
|    42 |     2 | # intersection is nonempty
|    54 |     5 | # sets are disjoint 
+-------+-------+`

Comment: You want to run the same query except only select specific values?

Comment: No. Consider the first query resulting in the first [value, count] table. I would like to find an analogous query that results in the second [value, count] table above. It still selects all the values, but it conditionally counts entity_id with value x OR y, instead of counting entity_id with value x.

Comment: So you are wanting a separate result set for each of the values in the first result table?

Answer (score 1):

```
select c1.value, 
( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entity_id) as count 
  FROM catalog_product_index_eav 
  where attribute_id=81 
  and (value=c1.value || value=7) ) as count 
FROM catalog_product_index_eav c1 
WHERE attribute_id=81 
GROUP BY c1.value
```

Comment: Thanks, this query provides the desired result. If anyone can come up with a more efficient query I will change accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: I've unaccepted this answer because the count does not respect WHERE parameters in the outer select. This is necessary for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Select C.value, max(C.count) from (
SELECT A.value, (Select COUNT(B.entity_id) from FROM catalog_product_index_eav B
WHERE B.attribute_id=A.attribute_id and (B.value=A.value or B.value=23)) AS count
FROM catalog_product_index_eav A
WHERE A.attribute_id=190) C group by C.value
```

Comment: Sorry but this isn't the correct logic. Using this query, I get back a ['value' => 22, 'count' => 7] pair. See original question, the query should only count unique entities.

Answer (score 0):

It gives you both results in single query if it is satisfied your output.

```
SELECT i.value AS [value], COUNT(i.entity_id) AS [count], 
(SELECT COUNT(b.entity_id) tot FROM catalog_product_index_eav b
        WHERE b.entity_id IN (SELECT v.entity_id FROM 
        catalog_product_index_eav v WHERE v.VALUE = i.value)) AS [total_count]
FROM catalog_product_index_eav i
WHERE i.attribute_id=190
GROUP BY i.value
```

Comment: Looks like there are syntax errors here, I can't run this SQL as is. My version is: `Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.16-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Comment: It's working fine in SQL 2012, can you please post the short error message

Comment: `ERROR 1064 (42000)`: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `OUTER APPLY(SELECT COUNT(entity_id) tot FROM catalog_product_index_eav` at line 3

Comment: Can you please check with above edited query, nothing changed more because I haven't anything there to change I have added just alias name and enclose column in square braces because sometime it gives error in other versions and in databases.